# Mac Mini with Lion wont start after Power failure...help!

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I was working on my Mac mini (Lion 10.7.2) when the power went off. When the power came, I started Mac Mini. But it keeps on showing grey screen with activity indicator forever. It wont start the system.

I have tried Repair Disk, Repair File Permissions, but still it wont start.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has guidelines explaining what to check for:

#### [Mac OS X: Gray screen appears during startup (support.apple.com)](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570)